# Is it possible to multiply a quaternion by a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, physics, tensors, rotations, quaternions

I have a rotation stored in a quaternion $\textbf{q}$ and an inertia tensor of a rigidbody $\mathit{I_b}$ ($b$ for body) stored in a $3\times 3$ matrix.

I would like to express my inertia tensor $\mathit{I_b}$ in a rotated frame $\{c\}$. luckily there is a formula utilizing a rotation matrix $\mathit{R_{bc}}$

$$\mathit{I_c} = \mathit{R^T_{bc}}\mathit{I_b}\mathit{R_{bc}}$$

What I'm wondering about is if it is possible to replace the rotation matrices with quaternions and to "combine" them directly with the inertia tensor $\mathit{I_b}$ **WITHOUT** first converting the quaternion to a $3\times3$ matrix.

In short order how would you multiply a quaternion or quaternion transpose by or into a $3\times3$ matrix?

perhaps something like this?

$$\mathit{I_c} = \mathit{q^T}\mathit{I_b}\mathit{q}$$

where $\mathit{q}$ is a unit quaternion representing rotation & $\mathit{q^T}$ is said quaternion's transpose.

Comment: It sounds like you know how to convert a quaternion to a $3\times 3$-matrix to obtain a rotation matrix. What is so cumbersome with that that you absolutely want to do it WITHOUT (your shouting) that conversion?

Comment: @KurtG. Mostly for program performance. one less instruction for the processor.

Comment: Have you profiled your program to be sure that this is a bottleneck? Hocus-pocus like $\mathit{I_c} = \mathit{q^T}\mathit{I_b}\mathit{q}$ is not going to work. If you want quaternions you have to convert the row and column vectors of $I_b$ to quaternions. The first principle is that a vector rotation $vR$ corresponds  to $q^{-1}vq\,.$ It should not be that hard to figure out the quaternion operations that reflect $R^\top I R$ as that is a sequence of vector rotations. If that speeds up your program is anyone's guess.

Comment: had typo: $vR$ should be $Rv$.